# Codeigniter 3 Mod_rewrite Plesk

Tags: codeigniter, iis, plesk

so I uploaded my website in GoDaddy and I used a Windows Hosting (Plesk). My only problem is that since it isn't running Apache as far as I know, it won't read my .htaccess file, which has all of my mod_rewrite code to remove the index.php in the URL. So my question is how do I implement a mod_rewrite in Plesk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite .htaccess file to IIS's web.config and place it inside /httpdocs folder.

You can do it by guides like [this](https://www.saotn.org/convert-htaccess-web-config/) or [this](http://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx) online converter or if you have Windows Server you can convert .htaccess by this [guide](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules) (or you can share your .htaccess and i'll try to convert it for you)

I've found this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/wmandai/d28cc45f10a19eec0fcb) maybe it can help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Index">
              <match url="^(.*)$" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```